# Returning an object from a LINQ query without casting it to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a LINQ query works when I set the return value to a `List`, however I just want to return an `IQueryable<Post>`. How would I do that?

```
public List<Post> GetPostByID(int id)
{
    var thePost = (from p in _context.Posts
                   where p.Id == id
                   select p).ToList();
    return thePost;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 public IQueryable<Post> GetPostByID(int id)
 {
        return (from p in _context.Posts
                       where p.Id == id
                       select p);
 }
```

Naturally due to deferred execution, this query will be executed at the put the caller tries to enumerate the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
var thePost = (from p in _context.Posts
                   where p.Id == id
                   select p);
    return thePost;
```